# Pandas Interpolate 'time' vs 'linear'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

In [Pandas `interpolate` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html), is `method='time'` equivalent to `method='linear'` when the time index is equally spaced?

A basic example suggests this is the case:

```py
even_index = pd.date_range('2019-02-20 10:00 am', 
                           '2019-02-20 2:00 pm', freq='1 h')
values = [10, np.nan, 30, np.nan, 50]

pd.DataFrame(values, index=even_index).interpolate(method='time')

                        0
2019-02-20 10:00:00  10.0
2019-02-20 11:00:00  20.0
2019-02-20 12:00:00  30.0
2019-02-20 13:00:00  40.0
2019-02-20 14:00:00  50.0


pd.DataFrame(values, index=even_index).interpolate(method='linear')

                        0
2019-02-20 10:00:00  10.0
2019-02-20 11:00:00  20.0
2019-02-20 12:00:00  30.0
2019-02-20 13:00:00  40.0
2019-02-20 14:00:00  50.0
```

A difference between 'time' and 'linear' only seems to occur if the time index is not equally spaced:

```py
uneven_index = pd.to_datetime(['2019-02-20 10:00 am', 
               '2019-02-20 10:30 am', '2019-02-20 12:30 pm', 
               '2019-02-20 1:30 pm', '2019-02-20 2:00 pm'])


pd.DataFrame(values, index=uneven_index).interpolate(method='time')

                             0
2019-02-20 10:00:00  10.000000
2019-02-20 10:30:00  14.000000
2019-02-20 12:30:00  30.000000
2019-02-20 13:30:00  43.333333
2019-02-20 14:00:00  50.000000

pd.DataFrame(values, index=uneven_index).interpolate(method='linear')

                        0
2019-02-20 10:00:00  10.0
2019-02-20 10:30:00  20.0
2019-02-20 12:30:00  30.0
2019-02-20 13:30:00  40.0
2019-02-20 14:00:00  50.0
```

My question is whether this always holds. Can it be assumed with an equally spaced time index, `method='time'` will always perform linear interpolation?

Answer (score 5):

Yes it is

From the documentation:

> ‘linear’: Ignore the index and treat the values as equally spaced

Therefore, if your index is equally spaced and you use the proper method ('time' method for a time index in your example, but it could also be the 'index' method for a numeric index with equally spaced values), you will indeed get the same result.

Comment: Thanks, I already read that in the documentation and that's what my example shows. I just wanted to confirm with someone who knows the internals of the library if `time` with equally spaced intervals is exactly equivalent to `linear`. This does not definitely answer the question.